# Yearling badge notified twice

Tags: discussion, meta, badges

> [image]

Both are for `meta.stackoverflow.com`. Is it a known bug or just related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just the child meta doing what it should be doing by acting as if it's as old as the parent site, thus badge awarding gets a *little* noisy initially. You'll get one yearling for each year of active participation on the main site (or the same number you have there).

Some will see an additional flurry of them when I start migrating some of the more recent and still relevant SO specific questions on MSE back here later today, when I get confirmation that I'm clear to use the SuperMultiCollidingRainbowBulkQuestionChucker tool.

Answer (score 6):

Because you completed 2 year on Stack Overflow. And you have been awarded two Yearling badges.

Check your profile:

[image: Badges]

It is because [Operation 'Split, All The Metas!' Shall Commence On April 16, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014)

Comment: Then, after 5 years, I will get 5 such notifications?

Comment: Yes, but this time last year I also got a notification like this.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: nope, You got 2 notification because those 2 badges are awarded today itself. Did you check this thread http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014 ? From today onwards there is some major changes in MSO.

Comment: I agree. The image is clear for me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

These were because of Operation [Split, All The Metas!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014), just a task like a system maintenance happened so some random things happened during the task being completed. I saw it as well, several times, maybe twice.